# Creating a news feed with libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, widget

I want to create sort of news feed like Facebook has using LibGDX. Is it possible? 
If no, what alternatives can i use?
I could try doing it manually, but i am sure there's an easier way of doing so.

Comment: Yes anything is possible, if you want further help you have to be a lot more clear and specific about what you want to achieve and what you have tried or researched.

Comment: Currently, i haven't tried anything. I want to be sure what i should use. I want to achieve a "news feed". It would contain all the "posts" that you can scroll through (using your finger, obviously). I'm quite sure LibGDX has API for that.

Comment: Where do you pull your data from? You write it yourself, inside the app? you want to hook into a database? Webservice and get XML? RSS feed? Tumblr API? We cannot possibly look into your mind.

Comment: I'd probably use google maps to gather information about nearby places. That doesn't actually matter. Let's say i want to add several pictures from file into my news feed. I want to be able to scroll through them. Similiar to how you can on facebok, twitter, 9gag mobile apps. Saw something called a scroll pane. Is that what i'm looking for?

Comment: A scroll pane is just a widget that allows you to add content that is larger then the pane itself and allows you to scroll trough the content. Nothing to do with news or feed.

Comment: Well, i want to add contrnt that i can scroll through. Isn't it what i'm looking for? I'll try them out when i get a free moment.

Comment: You want scroll functionality to display content.  A news feed is a app that reads data from x sources and displays them whether or not in a scrollable app. To answer your question. Yes, Libgdx has a `ScrollPane` in `Scene2d`. You should read about using `scene2d`, `stage` and `tables` before trying to implement it. If you want to have proper screen management then read about `screen` to.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually came to conclusion that it's not worth it using a library for games for app development, since Android studio has all the widgets and tools in place. Although i'd still use LibGDX for game development.